# flutter error all of a sudden the named parameter child isnt defined

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I changed my laptop and did a fresh install of android studio and flutter

and the app that was working before without any errors and warnings suddenly started throwing an **error and a warning**

[image]

**here is the code where the error is :**

```
          onTap: () async {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              child: Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 30,
                                  child: Center(
                                      child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                    radius: 20,
                                    animating: true,
                                  ))));
                          await handleFacebookLogin(context).then((user) {
                            navigationCheck(user, context);
                          }).then((_) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }).catchError((e) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          });
                        },
```

it was working perfectly before and it seems a bit strange that its throwing error on the new installation , can someone please guide me as to what the issue is here ?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

1. Clean the project cache by running

   `flutter clean cache`

Then invalidate caches / restart Android Studio

2. Restarted the dart analysis server

**But still the issue is the same**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) requires a `context` and a `builder`, not a `child`.

Try this:

```
onTap: () async {
   showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context) { 
           return Container(
               height: 30,
               width: 30,
               child: Center(
                   child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                       key: UniqueKey(),
                       radius: 20,
                       animating: true,
               ))));
```

Comment: is this because of some recent update in dart/flutter ? because the very same code was working 10 to 15 days ago and now its giving issues?

Comment: I don't know. Did you use the same Dart version on your previous project ?

Comment: yep it got rid of the above mentioned error , but something weird is going on , now its causing compilation errors which is really weird , in any case i will start and debug one error at a time